# Angular: Using $last to get last element visible using ng-show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

So I have an `ng-repeat` container div inside which I have a bunch of images. 
For each image, there is a div next to it. I want only the div of the final image to be visible and I achieve this using `$last`. This works like a charm.

Now I have a filter button in the page also, and when this button is clicked some of these images get hidden. This show/hide is done using `ng-show` on the image tag.

What I want is that when the filter button is clicked and some of the images are hidden, I want the div next to the final visible image to get shown. Seems like `$last` is not aware of the ng-show/hide value. How can I handle it so that the div next to the last visible image is still shown?

```
<div class='container' ng-repeat="image in album">
   <div class='wrapper' ng-show="getFilterValue(image.imageId)">
     <div><img src='{{image.src}}'></div>
     <div class='embellish-end' ng-class='{'hidden':!$last}'>The End</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, I too had some odd behavior with ng-repeat-start, $last and ng-show, ng-if.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ng-show you could filter the ng-repeat using angular's built in ng-repeat filter.  If your getFilterValue function returns a boolean this should work for you. Then your $last should know what is truly last based on what meets the filter criteria.

```
<div class='container' ng-repeat="image in album | filter:getFilterValue(image.imageId)">
   <div class='wrapper'>
     <div><img src='{{image.src}}'></div>
     <div class='embellish-end' ng-class='{'hidden':!$last}'>The End</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the ng-show on the image rather than the whole div wrapper:

```
<div class='container' ng-repeat="image in album">
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div ng-show="getFilterValue(image.imageId)"><img src='{{image.src}}'></div>
    <div class='embellish-end' ng-class='{'hidden':!$last}'>The End</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unrelated: use ***ng-src*** rather than ***src*** when using angularized image sources to avoid browser errors.